# Cast array to custom Object

Tags: php, laravel

I have an array that match the attributes of my ChampionshipSettings Class

So, I need my array to be a ChampionshipSetting object

The only thing I could do is :

```
 $settings = $championship->settings ??  (object)$mySettings;
```

But then $settings is an Object, not a ChampionshipSettings Object

If I try :

```
$settings = $championship->settings ??  (ChampionshipSettings)$mySettings;
```

I get a syntax error....

Any idea???

Comment: Create a factory, that builds ChampionshipSettings object from your array.

Comment: yep, it should do the trick.... But I'm from java world, and in Java it is very basic stuff, don't PHP allow you to do this kind of thing easily??

Comment: Type system is totally different comparing java and php.
If you want to transform (as an example) json into nested class structure, take a look at JMS Serializer for deserialization.
Even if PHP would support that kind of casting, factory looks safer and is easier to debug (implicit transformation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new object as:

```
$settings = $championship->settings ?? new ChampionshipSettings($mySettings);
```

Comment: it worked even if I declare explicitly a constructor! Tx